# Mantis Bug Tracker with OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, mantis

Has anyone implemented the Google OAuth 2.0 plugin in Mantis Bug Tracker?

I tried but could not make it work.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried.

Comment: I tried this this add-on but it did not work https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/GoogleOauth